# Fresh Install R Studio crashes

Tags: macos, rstudio

Tried posting this to R Studio's Support, but haven't gotten a response.  I need to install RStudio on a new computer, but get errors when trying to open the program.

Question: What is the problem with my R Studio install and how do I fix it?

- System: Mac 10.9.5
- R Version: 3.2.1 (seems to be properly installed)

Error upon opening the downloaded R Studio (0.99.447):

```
ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg=Error in identical(ns, .BaseNamespaceEnv) : 
7 arguments passed to .Internal(identical) which requires 5
, code=local(source("/Volumes/RStudio-0.99.447/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/R/Tools.R", local=TRUE, echo=FALSE, verbose=FALSE, keep.source=FALSE, encoding='UTF-8'))]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::r::exec::<anonymous namespace>::evaluateExpressionsUnsafe(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP *, sexp::Protect *) /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/r/RExec.cpp:149
```

I tried downloading an older version of R Studio (0.95.265). That one also gave an error:

```
The R session failed to start.

dyld: Symbol not found: RfxDevtoNDC
Referenced from: /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/rsession
Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
in /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/rsession
```

Thank you for any help in rectifying this.

Comment: If I click to open R from Applications, it brings up a R console window and allows me to run R commands.  I just can't run RStudio.

Comment: RStudio was installed, but will not load.  I want to run RStudio.  When I open the application, I get the above errors.  I can't figure out what they mean.  Question: What do these errors mean and how do I fix them?

Comment: I already did, as soon as I responded to you.

Comment: Yes, I added more, since you didn't seem to think it was enough.  Any actual solutions to my problem?  I really need R Studio installed before a class next week, and nowhere else online seems to have a solution.  And I don't have anyone in my lab who knows.

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to imply a missing library. What do you see in your terminal when you type the following:

```
Sys.which("R")
```

I'd also be interested in seeing your diagnostic report.

```
/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/RStudio --run-diagnostics
```

Comment: Sys.which("R"): 
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '"R"'

Does this mean R is installed improperly?

When I tried to run your second line in the Terminal, it just tried to open R and I got the same error message as is in my original problem above.

Answer (score 0):

If you have run older versions of R previously on your computer, I'd recommend that you check /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions, and delete older versions of R from the Versions folder. I had the same error, deleted the 2.11 version from the folder and this fixed it for me.

Comment: I've never run any version of R successfully on this computer.  I went in and deleted all these files and reinstalled.  Installation was successful, but I'm still receiving the same error as above (the second one).  :(